# Programmatically pre-populating remote help URL in for Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, rcp, tycho, eclipse-photon

I'm trying to build an Eclipse RCP application and have a remote help URL pre-populated in the *Preferences > Help > Content* table.

Is there an extension point or `.product` setting I can add to build an RCP application with a remote help link pre-populated?

I'd like to add a remote help entry here:

[image: Preference > Help > Content]

So when a user launches the application, a remote help is already defined.

Comment: Please make the question more descriptive.